# UIWebView Not loading

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am having a problem where UrlDisplay isn't displaying any data. UrlDisplay is located at the bottom of my .M. What I am doing is requesting a website collecting a few urls specific to the users request. Then setting up UiWebViews for them to navigate though is there any way to split a single UiWebView, or is this the best way to do it? (My sample is only collecting one website and trying to set one website to a UIWebView)I am not sure of why this is happening Everything in the .h is connected properly to the storyboard. Thanks for the help in advanced for any feed back!

.H

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *UrlDisplay;

@end
```

.M

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize UrlDisplay;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.Google.com"];



NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:website];



NSURLResponse* response = nil;

NSError *error = nil;

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

//storing data in a string

NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSArray *newString = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSMutableString *curLineNum;

NSString *curLine;

NSMutableArray *URL =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

int i;

for (i = 0; i <[newString count]; i++) {

    curLine = [newString objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([curLine rangeOfString:@"Start Here"].location != NSNotFound) {

        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:curLine];

        [scanner scanUpToString:@"Start Here" intoString:NULL];

        [scanner setScanLocation:([scanner scanLocation]) + 16];

        [scanner scanUpToString:@"End Here" intoString:&curLineNum];

        [Url addObject:curLineNum];


    }
}

NSURL *preWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:[Url objectAtIndex:0]];

NSURLRequest *preRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:preWebsite];

[UrlDisplay loadRequest:preRequest];
//NSLog(@"%@",myString);

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: if you print out your preWebsite what do you see?

Comment: Yes I set up NSData request for it to test that and it printed out fine. When I try to display it to the UIWebView it isn't loading. @incmiko

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", preWebsite); What do you see if you write this

Comment: <NSURLRequest: 0x892d370> { URL: https://itunes.apple.com } @incmiko

Comment: When i print the request i get the above when i print the preWebsite i get there same https://itunes.apple.com @incmiko

Comment: Did you assign your UIWebView with your IBOutlet?

Comment: Yes I control clicked the UIWebView from storyboard and dragged it to my .H to make the connection to my .H from The UIWebView, and then synthesize it in my .M. @incmiko

Comment: NSURL *preWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]; try this url pls

Comment: Sorry I got the same thing as I did before (preWebsite = www.google.com) (preRequest = <NSURLRequest: 0x8c3b3f0> { URL: www.google.com }) and still nothing is showing URLDisplay. @incmiko

Comment: Also be sure to drag from the UIWebView to the File’s Owner and select delegate.

Comment: @Rocker is right, URL must conforms to RFC 2396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method URLWithString always expecting full URL path including URL scheme. In your case URL scheme is missing. Try this.

```
NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.Google.com"];
```